# Proving span{V1, V2} is a subset of span{V1 + V2, V1 - V2}

Tags: linear-algebra

The actual proof is for the equality of the two sets, however I have proven the more straightforward direction (that span{V1 + V2, V1 - V2} is a subset of span{V1, V2}). Now I am finding difficulty proving the other direction.

I figure that  I have to find a way to manipulate span{V1, V2} in order for it to be in the form $$C_1(\vec{V_1}+\vec{V_2}) + C_2 (\vec{V_1}-\vec{V_2})$$
But I am unsure how to go about expressing $\vec{V_1}$ and $\vec{V_2}$ as a linear combination of the sum and difference of the two vectors.

Comment: Unless $v_1=v_2 = 0$ this cannot hold.

Comment: Do you mean $\text{span}\{v_1,v_2\} = \text{span}\{v_1+v_2, v_1-v_2\}$?

Comment: @Jolien Yes that is what I meant, I have edited the post now.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You probably meant that ${\rm span}\{v_1,v_2\} = {\rm span}\{v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2\}$. Take $v \in {\rm span}\{v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2\}$. So: $$v = a(v_1+v_2)+b(v_1-v_2) = (a+b)v_1+(a-b)v_2,$$ and $v \in {\rm span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. This proves that ${\rm span}\{v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2\}\subset {\rm span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. Do something similar for the other inclusion. Write: $$v_1 = \frac{(v_1+v_2)+(v_1-v_2)}{2},\quad v_2 = \frac{(v_1+v_2)-(v_1-v_2)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: calculate 
$$
(v_1+v_2) + (v_1 - v_2)
$$
and
$$
(v_1+v_2) - (v_1 - v_2).
$$